# Python object of type has no len()

Tags: python, object

I tried to solve an easy problem in leetcode. Here is the source: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/
I almost solved it with for loop, but i get an error Python object of type ListNode has no len(). I have tried to use **call**()  or **len**(), but i have no knowledge or understanding how does these built-in methods work. I read in many places, but the mess got bigger. If anyone could help me it would be great.

P.S. I know the solution with while loop is better, but i want this one to work somehow if possible. Or at least get some output.
`

```
**# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, sequence, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
#         self.sequence = sequence

class Solution:

    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:**
        j=0

        for i in range(0, len(head) - 1):

            if head[i-1-j] == head[i-j]:

                head.remove(head[i-j])
                j += 1
        head.remove(head[-1])    
        return head
```

`

Comment: Just loop over it once before so you know the length and then use that if you want.

Comment: Why do you expect `head[anything]` to work either? Getting `len` is useless to you here because you couldn't index into the custom list type even if you did know how many items there were.

Comment: @Chrispresso, _how_ exactly would the OP use the length if they had it? Their ListNode class doesn't support `__getitem__`

Comment: loop until you get a `head.next == None`, then you are at the end of the linked list
and you also have to do something with `x == head.val` to check something about the current value and then set `head = head.next` to iterate through the linked list

Comment: TBH I didn't look past `range`. But it wouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really decipher how your `ListNode` class is designed to work, but the answer to how to be able to call `len` on an instance of your own class is to define the `__len__` dunder method for the class. As others have pointed out in the comments, you'll also need to define the `__getitem__` method in order to be able to do stuff like `head[i-1-j]`. It might look something like this (just guessing as to the actual definitions as it's not clear to me how you want the class to work):

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, sequence, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
        self.sequence = sequence

    def __len__(self):

        return len(self.sequence)   # Maybe? Or whatever you want len to return

    def __getitem__(self, i):

        return self.sequence[i]     # Maybe? Or whatever you want [ ] to return
```

More on dunder methods [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/27/underscoring-or-dunder-scoring-the-importance-of-native-type-methods-in-python/).

Comment: Thing is, future items are supposed to come from `self.next`; just iterating over `self.sequence` doesn't suffice. And the goal of the exercise is to with with the existing class definition; it's a Python version of the classic intro-to-C exercise of building a linked list.

Comment: If you follow the OP's link, there's no `self. sequence` there in the original problem definition at all. I have no idea where it came from when they asked the question.